# Network Adapter Batch Identification

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, networking

I am attempting to create a batch script that will allow for the identification of the network connections (Updated).

This is a much simpler version than what I had before, however running into issues when calling the if statement.

```
@echo off
wmic nic get NetConnectionID, NetConnectionStatus
set Connection=(wmic path Win32_NetworkAdapter Where AdapterTypeID=0)
set Status=(wmic path Win32_NetworkAdapter Where NetConnectionStatus=2)

IF %Connection% and %Status% ( 
echo %computername% is connected to the network via Ethernet Wired/Wireless
Pause
::exit /b 2 
) ELSE (
echo %computername% is not connected to a Network
Pause
::exit /b 1
)
```

Comment: You're going to want to take a look at the output of `if /?`

Comment: Sorry for adding it in the comments, updated the question

Answer (score 0):

You can only set the result of a command to a variable by using a `for /f` loop. For example, `%Connection%` would be set like this:

```
for /f %%A in ('wmic path Win32_NetworkAdapter Where AdapterTypeID=0') do set Connection=%%A
```

**HOWEVER**
If you look at the actual output of `wmic path Win32_NetworkAdapter Where AdapterTypeID=0`, you'll see that there is *way* too much data in there for your variable to be useful. Additionally, you can combine your two `wmic` queries into one, eliminating the need for an `if` statement altogether.

```
echo The following computers are connected to the network via Ethernet/Wireless:
wmic path Win32_NetworkAdapter where "AdapterTypeId=0 and NetConnectionStatus=2" get SystemName
pause
```

If you only want to return an errorlevel based on whether or not any are actually found, you have to redirect STDERR to STDOUT and then look for the string that gets returned when no instance is found. This means that the script returns 1 if it finds any connected computers and 0 if it does not (this is the opposite of normal errorlevel values).

```
wmic path Win32_NetworkAdapter where "AdapterTypeId=0 and NetConnectionStatus=2" 2>&1|find "No Instance"
echo %errorlevel%
```

It's also worth noting that batch doesn't have support for logic in `if` statements, so you can only simulate `and`s by nesting `if`s.

Comment: So only if the wmic path is correct then it will pull the system name? If I wanted to return an errorlevel if the path was true then how would I go about that?